# Laravel 7 validation rule filled or present doesn't work on dynamically generated select

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-7

I have problem when i generate select dynamically by other select value to validate it. For example select1 one has values 1,2,3,4, if selected values 2,4 then i generate dynamically select 2 otherwise if select1 values 1,3 i don't generate select2. The idea is when select2 exists it should be required. I'am using Laravel 7 when i use rule present it requirs select2 even if doesn't exist in dom. When i tried to use filled it doesn't give any error if select2 exists or not. Can someone tell what wrong i'am doing ?

blade code:

```
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-4">
          <select class="form-control lygis1" id="lygis1" name="select1">
             <option value="" disabled selected>Pasirinkite 1 lygį</option>
             <option value="1">1</option>
             <option value="2">2</option>
             <option value="3">3</option>
             <option value="4">4</option>
         </select>
       </div>
       <div class="col-4" id="lygis2">
          If select1 value 2,4 i generate here select2 with name select2
       </div>
 <div>
```

Validation rule code:

```
$validateData = $request->validate([
            'select1' => 'required',
            'select2' => 'filled', //tried present
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that validation works when I remove disabled and leave only selected from select.

Answer (score 0):

You can use required_if rule : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-required-if

```
    $validateData = $request->validate([
        'select1' => 'required',
        'select2' => 'required_if:select1,2'
        ]);
```